# For each code not making check box value true

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to create code that runs through a list of user ID's (B Numbers) and then when it finds the corresponding ID it checks to see if there's an X in the column directly next to it for a certain subject named SBB005 [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4NOc.png). If there is an X, I want the check box value to be true. The for each loop ends when it reaches a blank cell.

I have declared the 'RowYear2' and 'Year2CourseRange' ranges as public variables, and when running the code, nothing happens and the check box remains unticked! Any idea why the checkbox isn't being ticked as expected?

I am planning on setting up multiple checkboxes once this is working for all the subjects in each column:
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4NOc.png)

Hoping that someone can help me to get this working or may even introduce an easier way to do so for another 20 checkboxes!

Many thanks :)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Set Year2CourseRange = Sheets("Year2").Range("A:A")

For Each RowYear2 In Year2CourseRange.Cells
    If RowYear2.Value = BNumberTxt Then
        If RowYear2.Offset(0, 1) = "x" Then
            Me.CHKSBB005.value = True
        Else
            Me.CHKSBB005.value = False
        End If
    ElseIf IsEmpty(RowYear2) Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next RowYear2

LoggedInTxt = Row.Offset(0, -3)
BNumberTxt = Row.Offset(0, -7)
CourseTxt = Row.Offset(0, -1)
CourseNumTxt = Row.Offset(0, -2)

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub EnterBtn_Click()

Dim LIMatch As Boolean
Dim Win As Boolean

Email = Me.EmailTxt
Password = Me.PasswordTxt

Set UserRange = Sheets("StudentInformation").Range("H:H")

For Each Row In UserRange.Cells
    If Me.EmailTxt = "" And Me.PasswordTxt = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter an email and password")
        LIMatch = False
        Win = True
    Exit For
    ElseIf Me.EmailTxt = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter an email address")
        LIMatch = False
        Win = True
    Exit For
    ElseIf Me.PasswordTxt = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter a password")
        LIMatch = False
        Win = True
    Exit For

    Else

        If UCase(Row.Value) = UCase(Email) Then
            If UCase(Row.Offset(0, -6)) = UCase(Password) Then
                MsgBox "Welcome"
                LIMatch = True
                Win = True
                Attempts = 0
                Exit For
            ElseIf IsEmpty(Row) Then
                Exit For
                Win = False
            Else
                LIMatch = False
                Win = False

            Exit For
            End If
        Else
            LIMatch = False
            Win = False
        End If

    End If
    Next Row

If LIMatch = True And Win = True Then
    Unload Me
    NewForm.Show
ElseIf LIMatch = False And Win = False Then
    MsgBox ("Incorrect login")
    Attempts = Attempts + 1
Else
End If

If Attempts >= 3 Then
MsgBox ("You have entered the incorrect login 3 times")
Unload Me
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Option Explicit` specified? What is `Row`?

Comment: Row refers to another public variable from a previous form, the code above the for loop does appear to work, the loop is where the error is occurring. I've added option explicit to the top but now I'm getting an error saying 'invalid inside procedure'.

Comment: So, which line is throwing the error specifically?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure which line is causing the error :( just know it's somewhere in the for loop.

Comment: That would be the line that's highlighted when you hit "Debug" when the error pops up. Make sure the VBE options are configured to "break on all errors".

Comment: Thanks for the tip, debug wasn't showing for me but after selecting 'break on all errors' it did, and apparently the error came from the LoggedInTxt = Row.Offset(0,-3) line. I moved that entire 'sign in details' code below the for loop code and there now seems to be no error. However when I run the code the checkbox is not checked as expected, any idea why? thanks!

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your post with the new info :)

Comment: Now you're searching for `BNumberTxt` before you've set its value from `Row`

Comment: It would help to add the code where you set the global `Row` and launch the form.

Comment: You got some pretty solid answers. Vandalizing your post will lose useful replies and is very disrespectful towards the people who took the time to try to help you. The content you submitted when you posted this question was transferred to the ownership of Stack Overflow when you asked this question.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit because it rendered the code invalid. The effort to make the code shorter would be welcome per se, but you need to take care to not introduce errors, and also make sure it doesn't make the answer harder to understand (which will often be the case when the answer was in response to an earlier version of the code).

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix your problem with the `Row` global, you can do something like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim shtData As Worksheet
    Dim Year2CourseRange As Range, HeaderRange As Range, m, c As Range

    Set shtData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Year2")
    With shtData
        Set Year2CourseRange = .Range("A:A")
        Set HeaderRange = .Range(.Range("B2"), .Cells(2, 500).End(xlToLeft))
    End With

    'you'll need to fix this part....
    BNumberTxt = Row.Offset(0, -7)
    'etc

    'find a matching row: Match() is a good approach here
    m = Application.Match(BNumberTxt, Year2CourseRange, 0)

    'loop over all the column headers
    For Each c In HeaderRange.Cells
        'Assumes all checkboxes are named "CHK[ColumnHeaderHere]"
        With Me.Controls("CHK" & c.Value)
            If IsError(m) Then
                .Value = False  'clear all if no match
            Else
                .Value = (UCase(shtData.Cells(m, c.Column)) = "X") 'set if "x"
            End If
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This look great! Thank you! I'm just slightly confused as to how to fix the row part? It's a public variable and the row value comes from a previous for loop from another form.

Comment: Hence my comment above to add that code to your question - I can't suggest how to fix that without seeing the code where you set the value.

Comment: Apologies I misunderstood, have added the code now :)

Comment: Where is your `Row` global declared?

Comment: It's in a module, and under General and Declarations it's declared as 'Public Row as Range'

Comment: Change it to something more distinctive like `gUserRow` and set it explicitly from your login - something like `MsgBox "Welcome":Set gUserRow = Row`

Answer (score 0):

## Ranges and Ranges

This is your code squashed a little bit and below is your data:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Set Year2CourseRange = Sheets("Year2").Range("A:A")
For Each RowYear2 In Year2CourseRange.Cells
    If RowYear2.Value = BNumberTxt Then
        If RowYear2.Offset(0, 1) = "x" Then
            Me.CHKSBB005.value = True
        Else: Me.CHKSBB005.value = False: End If
    ElseIf IsEmpty(RowYear2) Then
        Exit For: End If: Next RowYear2
  LoggedInTxt = Row.Offset(0, -3): BNumberTxt = Row.Offset(0, -7)
  CourseTxt = Row.Offset(0, -1): CourseNumTxt = Row.Offset(0, -2): End Sub
```

[image]

Take a look for a while, you might see the error yourself.

### The CheckBox Tick Mystery

When you write `Range("A:A")` that refers to the whole column including `Range("A1")` which appears to be `EMPTY`. The code never even enters the If `RowYear2.Offset...` line but exits via the  `ElseIf` line.

### The Row Variable

I hate the idea of declaring a variable `Row`. But it is valid. Since there is an `Offset` involved, `Row` should be a range, probably a cell. As in the comments indicated, it has to 'survive' from another UserForm let's say `UserFormX`. If it has 'survived' you have to refer to it like this:

```
UserFormX.Row
```

or you have to declare it in a 'not-object' module to use only `Row`.

### Another EnterBtn_Click

Probably useless now but here is the code I worked on the other day:

```
Option Explicit

Public intAttempts As Integer

Private Sub CancelBtn_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub EnterBtn_Click()

    Const strEmail = "Please enter email address."   ' Email Input Message
    Const strPassword = "Please enter a password."   ' Password Input Message
    Const strLoginCorrect = "Welcome"                ' Correct Login Message
    Const strLoginIncorrect = "Incorrect Login."     ' Incorrect Login Message
    Const strAttempts = "Too many login attempts."   ' Login Attempts Message

    ' Use worksheet name or index e.g. "SInfo" or 1.
    Const vntWsName As String = "StudentInformation" ' Worksheet
    ' Use column letter or column number e.g. "F" or 6.
    Const vntEmailColumn As Variant = "F"            ' Email Column
    Const intFirstRow As Integer = 2                 ' Email Column First Row
    Const intPasswordColumnOffset As Integer = -4    ' Password Column Offset
    Const intMaxAttempts As Integer = 3              ' Maximum Login Attempts

    Dim lngCounter As Long                           ' Email Column Row Counter
    Dim lngLastrow As Long                           ' Email Column Last Row

    ' Check number of login attempts.
    If intAttempts >= intMaxAttempts Then
        MsgBox strAttempts
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Show annoying text messages if nothing was entered.
    If Me.EmailTxt.Text = "" Then
        Me.EmailTxt.Text = strEmail: Exit Sub
      ElseIf Me.EmailTxt.Text = strEmail Then Exit Sub
    End If
    If Me.PasswordTxt.Text = "" Then
        Me.PasswordTxt.Text = strPassword: Exit Sub
      ElseIf Me.PasswordTxt.Text = strPassword Then Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Check for data in specified worksheet.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vntWsName)

        ' Determine last row of data in Email Column.
        lngLastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, vntEmailColumn).End(xlUp).Row

        For lngCounter = intFirstRow To lngLastrow
            ' Ceck for email in Email Column.
            If UCase(.Cells(lngCounter, vntEmailColumn).Value) _
                    = UCase(EmailTxt.Text) Then ' Correct email.
                ' Check if correct password in Password Column
                If UCase(.Cells(lngCounter, vntEmailColumn) _
                        .Offset(0, intPasswordColumnOffset).Value) _
                        = UCase(PasswordTxt.Text) Then ' Correct password.
                    Exit For
                  Else ' Wrong password. Set "counter" to "end".
                    ' Faking that the loop was not interrupted.
                    lngCounter = lngLastrow
                End If
'              Else ' Wrong Email. Do nothing. Not necessary.
            End If
        Next
        ' When the loop wasn't interrupted, "lngcounter = lnglastrow + 1".

    End With

    ' Check if loop was NOT interrupted.
    If lngCounter = lngLastrow + 1 Then ' Loop was NOT interrupted.
        intAttempts = intAttempts + 1
        MsgBox strLoginIncorrect
      Else ' Loop was interrupted. Correct email and password.
        MsgBox strLoginCorrect
        Unload Me
        NewForm.Show
    End If

End Sub
```